# mongo docker image not running script after created

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm using docker-compose to create 3 diferent containers for a frontend, backend and mongo instance. the 3 of them are running and connected between them, but I need to create an admin user on DB as soon as the mongo instance is running.  According to mongo image documentation every script located on `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` should be run after the instance is created. As I already said I'm using docker compose so theres no `Dockerfile` for mongo, just a service using the official mongo image so I've set a volume to this file [don't know if because of that the script is not running, because is a symlink instead of a copied file]. So I tried to run a command to run this script but it doesn't work, but if then I do a `docker exec` to the mongodb instance and run the script by myself it will work and create the admin user.

So, how can i make this script run after the instance is created?

this is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    command: /bin/bash "cd /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d && mongo-init.sh"
    networks:
      - backend-network
    volumes:
      - './db:/data/db'
      - './mongo-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh'
    tty: true
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to modify the mongo command because it will cause issues to the mongodb container. By defining `command` you will override [the original `CMD`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/4.1/Dockerfile#L97) which expected to run. the script will be executed automatically as long as you have mounted it under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` as explained in [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/4.1/docker-entrypoint.sh#L318-L325)

Note that scripts will be executed only one time at the start of your container and in order to make it execute again you need to delete the `/data/db` volume which is associated with your container

Comment: as I've already said, the .sh file is on the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` but is not being executed unless I exec bash on the container and run it by myself.

Comment: Please try it again without adding exec and update your question with the container log. **and make sure to delete any volumes used by the same container**

Comment: @Miguelopezv note that the execution of these scripts happens only on the first time you run the container that's why i asked you to delete any previous volumes that was used by the container to make it start as a fresh setup