# docker-entrypoint-initdb.d not executing scripts

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-entrypoint

I'm using `docker-compose version 1.25.5, build 8a1c60f6` &
`Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b`

I'm trying to initialise database with Users in MongoDb container using `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` but,
js/scripts aren't being executed when container starts.

I know `/data/db` must be empty for it execute so I've been deleting it every time before start. But still doesn't execute. Going into the container and manually executing `mongo mongo-init.js` works.

Not sure why it's not working when it should.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: "mongodb"
    image: tonyh308/cv-mongodb:1
    build: ./mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test
    volumes:
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
      - ./mongo/mongodb:/data/db
    labels:
      com.qa.description: "MongoDb Container for application."

# other services ...
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:3.6.18-xenial
RUN apt-get update
COPY ./Customers /Customers
COPY ./test /test
WORKDIR /data
ENTRYPOINT ["mongod", "--bind_ip_all"]
EXPOSE 27017
```

Feb 26 2021: still no solution

Comment: Can you just remove the volume and see if this works on a fresh non-mounted directory?

Comment: Still doesn't work. And I did check there are no existing volumes before hand.

Comment: What do the logs say? Do they mention anything about running init scripts?

Comment: According to the entrypoint shell script, you must see this log when it is supposed to run the init scripts: `MongoDB init process complete; ready for start up.` [source](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/be3c690cae52447831b977dab9c6a66dc993df65/3.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L342)

Comment: @AliTou I've updated above with log. Nothing about MongoDB init process.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799937/mongo-docker-image-not-running-script-after-created